# Stuck in a redirection loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I got a web hosting service which got a text file name Redirect.txt, what Im trying to do is do a check every 5 seconds using intrevals, so basically every 5 seconds im sending a fetch request to a text file and if the content is not equal to # ill redirect the user to the content of the file. Im also doing another check so the user wouldnt get redirected infinitely, im just using a var named usedLink, if the text file content is not equal to usedLink it will redirect the user.

Here is my code:

```
var usedLink;
setInterval(read_redirect(), 5000);
function read_redirect(){

  var url = `${SERVER_HOST}/Redirect.txt`;
  fetch(url, {
  mode: "no-cors"
})
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    const textData = data;
    console.log(textData + ": used");
    if (textData != "#" && textData != usedLink) {
        usedLink = textData;
        console.log(usedLink + " : USED LINK")
        location.href = textData;
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

I tried adding a small delay before the redirection so the response to the fetch request could reach the server, but the user is still being redirected non stop.
However this is my output:
https://youtube.com/: used
https://youtube.com/ : USED LINK
: used
: USED LINK
: used
: USED LINK ... and so on

Comment: Remove `()` in setInterval line.

Comment: Don't use `no-cors` if you intend to read the body.